# Move "current" class between tab menu based on Selection

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML code based on a tab menu format, i.e:

```
 <div id="listnav">
  <ul id="nav">
     <li id="home"><a href="#" id="current">Home</a></li>
     <li id="features"><a href="#">Features</a></li>
     <li id="whysp"><a href="#">Why sP</a></li>
     <li id="screenshots"><a href="#">Screen Shots</a></li>
     <li id="faq"><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
     <li id="contactus"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

When first coming into the web page, my Home tab is set as current based on the id="current" within the a href tag.

My question is, when the user clicks on the "Features" tab, how can I through jQuery, remove the class=current from the Home tab and add to the Features a href tag, so that my Features tab now displays as te current tab and so on with the others?

I also have the following jQuery functions:

```
$("#home").click(function(){
    $("#content").load('home.html');
});

$("#features").click(function(){
    $("#content").load('features.html');
});
```

Comment: You typed, "remove the id=current", and I think you meant, "remove the class=current".

Comment: thanks Pointy - have updated my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#nav a').click(function(){
   $("#nav").find("a").removeAttr("id");
   $(this).attr("id" , "current" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#nav a').click(function(){
 $(this).attr('id','current').parent('li').siblings()
        .children('a').removeAttr('id');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you could use a class named 'current' and then remove/add using `.removeClass()` and `.addClass()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#features").click(function(){
    $("#current").removeAttr("id");
    $("#features a").attr("id", "current");
    $("#content").load('features.html');
});
```

I would recommend to use a class current instead of an ID

Answer (score 0):

No need to repeat your navigation code for each link :-)

```
$("#nav li a").click(function()
{
    // Remove old current
    $("#current").removeAttr("id");
    // Set new current
    $(this).attr("id", "current");
    // Load content for clicked nav
    $("#content").load($(this).closest("li").attr("id") + '.html');
    // Prevent click from jumping to the top of the page
    return false;
});
```